# How to move VSCode menu bar to system position

Tags: visual-studio-code

VSCode provides its bar menu position. Is it possible to display the bar menu from the system settings? (as shown in screenshot 2)

[vscode default menu bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUcNr.png)

[system menu bar example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0xow1.png)

I looked at all the VSCode settings and it only provides the option to hide/show the menu bar

There is also a setting "Window -> Experimental: Native Context Menu Location", which in theory should solve my problem, but it doesn’t change anything

Comment: Welcome! this might come down to being an electron question actually. Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.

Answer (score 0):

The only other option that is closely related to what you need is the `Window: Title Bar Style` option, where you can switch between native and custom modes.

You can try switching to "custom", I noticed on Ubuntu that it does change the layout of the Menu bar items.